# This code runs for grid<=11 but gets stuck forever for grid>=12. Can anyone explain why this happens? (Using p5.js library of JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Basically the title. I have read every line many times and still can't find my mistake.
I am just trying to put squares on a grid by calling a recursive function which creates the object and then calls itself again. I have checked that recursion is not infinite and there's a simple exit condition. Please help.

```
let grid = 11;
let sqr = [];
function setup() {
  createCanvas(grid * grid, grid * grid);
  noFill();
  colorMode(HSB);
  noLoop();
  let maxs = floor(grid / 3);
  let ratio = 2 * maxs * maxs;
  makegrid(maxs, ratio);
}
function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (let sq of sqr) sq.show();
}
function makegrid(m, r) {
  if (!m) return;
  if (m == floor(grid / 3)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) sqr.push(new sqrs(m, r));
    m--;
    makegrid(m, r);
  } else {
    let j = r / (m * m);
    for (let k = 0; k < j; k++) sqr.push(new sqrs(m, r));
    m--;
    makegrid(m, r);
  }
}

class sqrs {
  constructor(m, r) {
    let flag = true;
    this.s = (m * width) / grid;
    while (flag) {
      flag = false;
      this.x = (width / grid) * floor((grid + 1 - m) * random());
      this.y = (height / grid) * floor((grid + 1 - m) * random());
      if (!sqr.length) flag = false;
      else {
        for (let sq of sqr) {
          let d = (this.x - sq.x) ** 2 + (this.y - sq.y) ** 2;
          if (d < this.s ** 2 || d < sq.s ** 2) {
            flag = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  show() {
    stroke(random(340), 80, 80);
    square(this.x, this.y, this.s);
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions? What libraries and their versions are you using?

Comment: I am using p5.js library. Thanks, I updated the title.

Comment: The recursion is not infinite, but the `for` loop inside constructor can be. At some point it becomes impossible for the code to place all the squares separate (not intersecting). 
Btw, it also can have troubles with `grid = 9`.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. No matter how many times my code tries, there are not any possible locations that satisfies the conditions, so the codes runs forever. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jay pointed out in the comments, it's not the recursion that is the problem, but the `while (flag)` loop in your `sqrs` constructor that is the problem:

```js
let grid = 12;
let sqr = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(grid * grid, grid * grid);
  noFill();
  colorMode(HSB);
  noLoop();
  // maxs will be 4 if grid is 12
  let maxs = floor(grid / 3);
  // ratio will be 32
  let ratio = 2 * maxs * maxs;
  makegrid(maxs, ratio);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (let sq of sqr) sq.show();
}

function makegrid(m, r) {
  if (m <= 0) return;
  if (m == floor(grid / 3)) {
    // Call 0: m == floor(grid / 3) == 4
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) sqr.push(new sqrs(m, r));
    m--;
    // Call 0: makegrid(3, 32);
    makegrid(m, r);
  } else {
    // Call 1: j = 32 / (3 * 3) = 3.55555
    // Call 2: j = 32 / (2 * 2) = 8
    // Call 3: j = 32 / (1 * 1) = 32
    let j = r / (m * m);
    for (let k = 0; k < j; k++) sqr.push(new sqrs(m, r));
    m--;
    // Call 1: makegrid(2, 32)
    // Call 2: makegrid(1, 32)
    // Call 3: makegrid(0, 32)
    makegrid(m, r);
  }
}

class sqrs {
  constructor(m, r) {
    let flag = true;
    this.s = (m * width) / grid;
    // This code might end up repeating forever because every randomly generated
    // position is too close to some existing square
    let count = 0;
    while (flag && ++count < 1000) {
      flag = false;
      this.x = (width / grid) * floor((grid + 1 - m) * random());
      this.y = (height / grid) * floor((grid + 1 - m) * random());
      if (sqr.length) {
        // Check if the new square is too close to any existing squares
        for (let sq of sqr) {
          let d = (this.x - sq.x) ** 2 + (this.y - sq.y) ** 2;
          if (d < this.s ** 2 || d < sq.s ** 2) {
            flag = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (flag) {
      this.s = 0;
      print(`gave up after ${count} attempts to find a position for this square.`);
    }
  }

  show() {
    stroke(random(340), 80, 80);
    square(this.x, this.y, this.s);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

The logic in that while loop doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, so you're going to have to describe what you are actually trying to do if you want more advice.

Comment: Thank you. I got the point you and Jay are making.
About the logic in while loop, I am just starting to build something, so it doesn't make much sense now. But you perfectly solved my problem, thanks for that. If I get in more trouble later on (I probably will), I will ask again.